# `String#gsub` on first match

Tags: ruby, regex, gsub

I have a string as follows:

```
string = "request=hxxp://abc.com/user=username?pass=password"
```

and I need to substitute the first instance of the equals character `"="` to `"***"`. I'm hoping to achieve:

```
string = "request***hxxp://abc.com/user=username?pass=password"
```

I tested with the following, but no luck:

```
string = string.gsub(/^[^=]+(=)/,'***') # => "***hxxp://..."
string = string.gsub(/((?<=())=)/,'***') # => all "=" replaced with "***"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to use `gsub`? This is probably an XY-question.

Comment: You know that "gsub" means "sub, but global", right? :)

Comment: Why do you need to use a regex (as tagged)? This is probably an XY-question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use sub. This should replace the first occurance of `=` only.

```
string.sub(/=/, "***")
```

For gsub, it must be

```
string.gsub(/^([^=]*)=/,'\1***')
```

Comment: correcting a typo on your gsub... I like ur solution! 

string.gsub(/^([^=]*)=/,"#{$1}***")